# How can I make a setup for my python codes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation

I have written a program using some modules such as `NLTK` as my university project. The problem is my TA cannot run my code because of the modules.
I want to know how can I make a setup for my codes so that others don't have to install the module I have used to execute my code.

Comment: you mean an installer? Which platform do you want to deploy?

Comment: My program is on Linux. I think I would need both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

While the best method is to use setuptools, but there is a simpler solution which I use when I don't want my users to have to download the dependencies.

To bundle the modules along with your script, create the following directory structure:

```
Project_directory
  |--My_Script1.py
  |--My_Script2.py
  |--modules
        |-nltk (copied here from the installation directory)
        |-other_module_directory
```

Note that all the non-default modules should be copied to the `modules` directory.

Then, at the top of your main script, add the following lines:

```
import os
import sys

SRC_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MODULES_DIR = os.path.join(SRC_DIR, "modules")
sys.path.append(MODULES_DIR)

import nltk  #This should work now
```

Now you can ship your project by `tar`ing or zipping the Project_directory.